# Creating a lens(like) for list

Tags: haskell, lenses

I'm trying to create lenses for the following data structure. I'm using [`lens-family`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-family).

```
data Tree = Tree {
        _text :: String,
        _subtrees :: [Tree]
    } deriving (Show,Eq,Read,Generic)
```

I'd like to avoid using Template Haskell for various reasons. For one, it seems it's not available for my version of ghc (7.8.3), that's another (out of scope) problem.

Creating lenses for the record wasn't to hard.

```
text :: Lens' Tree String
text f (Tree text' subtrees') =
  (\text'' -> Tree text'' subtrees') `fmap` (f text')

subtrees :: Lens' Tree [Tree]
subtrees f (Tree text' subtrees') =
  (\subtrees'' -> Tree text' subtrees'') `fmap` (f subtrees')
```

But it seems that lens-family doesn't have default lenses for lists. I assume this is possible. There are for the [`lens` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-1.3.1/docs/Data-List-Lens.html). These are my failed attempts:

```
import Lens.Family2
import Lens.Family2.Unchecked
-- List lenses
_last :: Lens [a] [a'] a a'
_last f l =
  -- first try
  --lens getter setter
  -- second try
  (\el -> (init l) ++ el) `fmap`(f (last l))
  where
    getter = last
    setter l el = l ++ el
```

They both get an error akin to this one:

```
Could not deduce (a' ~ [a'])
    from the context (Functor f)
      bound by the type signature for
                 _last :: Functor f => LensLike f [a] [a'] a a'
      at editor.hs:22:10-27
      ‘a'’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             _last :: Functor f => LensLike f [a] [a'] a a'
           at editor.hs:22:10
    Expected type: f [a']
      Actual type: f a'
    Relevant bindings include
      f :: a -> f a' (bound at editor.hs:23:7)
      _last :: LensLike f [a] [a'] a a' (bound at editor.hs:23:1)
    In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(f (last l))’
    In the expression: (\ el -> (init l) ++ el) `fmap` (f (last l))
```

**How can I define the `_last` lens?**

**Edit:** Here's a version that builds:

```
_last f l = (\el -> (init l) ++ [el]) `fmap`(f (last l))
```

Although, as David/Daniel points out, `_last` should be a Traversal, not a lens.

Comment: Sort of off-topic, but I have ideological problems with this question: `_last` cannot be a lens, for essentially the same reason `last` cannot be a function.

Comment: FWIW Template Haskell is definitely "available" for 7.8.3; it comes with every GHC installation that supports it, which is all of them except possibly for unusual architectures (non-x86/x86_64).

Comment: @ReidBarton Ok then, misunderstood the root cause of the dependency resolution problems. I felt it would be nicer to go without templates/keep deps to a minimum for this particular project though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing square brackets around `el` (`(++)` takes a list for both arguments). Your first try should work if you put them in. Your type is also too general. Lists aren't heterogenous in Haskell, so they can only contain values of one type.

Also, as Daniel Wagner says, this can't be a true lens because it is partial. The lens documentation you linked to is out of date. The current lens library has [`_last` as a `Traversal`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.9/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_last) which avoids this problem because a `Traversal` can have 0 or more targets, as opposed to a lens which must have exactly 1.

Comment: Yes. All those things are things I already know but failed to think about. Guess that's what happens when I try to do haskell while also doing other stuff. :)